# how to use ngif for a value in html

Tags: angular

I want to use ngif to assign value to a text box. My use case is if total hours is greater than 40 than assign the value as 40 else assign the total hours. I tried using this code but i am getting error

```
 <ng-template *ngIf="{{this.result > 40}}">
        <input id="regularHours" type="number" value=40 class="form-control">
      </ng-template>
```

Error: Type '{ "": undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Not sure what i am doing wrong here, Can someone please help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*ngIf` expects a boolean expression "as code" like `*ngIf="true"`

`{{ x }}` is used to display/print an expression.

In your case, you should update your code to:

```html
*ngIf="this.result > 40"
```

Answer (score 1):

For this use case you could consider just manipulating the input value directly, to save a few lines of code - this would give the same result:

```
    <input id="regularHours" type="number" [value]="result > 40 ? 40 : result" class="form-control">
```

Also, 'this' is not necessary when using vars in the template.